# Replace CSS file if is specific subdomain, using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Regular Expressions are still a stone in my boot. Can you help me, guys?

I have this piece of code for a hook in a CMS. Actually it is the whole code enclosed in the function to be excecuted by the main code.

```
if (preg_match('#^/member/helpdesk/index.*#i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) //do it only for specific url
{
    $event->replace('#(<h1>Tickets.*</h1>)#i', '$1<div>Some content</div>');
}
```

But what I really want is to check if the pages belongs to subdomain `member.site.com`, find the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://site.com/orange.css"/>` and replace `orange.css` by `blue.css`

Thank you :)

Comment: What is contained where?  I think we need to see what variables you're using, what they contain, and what you'd like them to contain.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan It's just this. It's a hook for a CMS. This is the whole code of the function. I just need to make it detect if the current page belongs to subdomain `http://member.site.com`, and if true, replace `orange.css` by `blue.css`. The rest will be executed by the main code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean, at the core I think you're trying to do this:

```
$str = '<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://site.com/style.css"/></head></html>'
if (preg_match('#member\.site\.com#i'), $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])){
    $str = preg_replace('#http://site\.com/style\.css#', 'http://site.com/style-member.css', $str);
}
```

But perhaps you should consider how whatever it is you're trying to replace is being generated in the first place?  Perhaps this is a check that could be placed at that location?  Additionally, if you're going to be modifying an html document, I highly suggest using a parser of some kind.  If you're going to do the first, maybe something like this:

```
$head = '<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://site.com/style';
if (preg_match('#member\.site\.com#i'), $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])){
    $head .= '-member';
}
$head .= '.css"></head>';
```

But if you insist on parsing an html document:

```
$str = '<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://site.com/style.css"/></head></html>'
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
if (preg_match('#member\.site\.com#i'), $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])){
    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('link');
    foreach ($links as $link){
        $attr = $link->attributes;
        if ($attr 
                && $attr->getNamedItem('rel')->nodeValue == 'stylesheet'
                && $attr->getNamedItem('href')->nodeValue == 'http://site.com/style.css'){
            $attr->getNamedItem('href')->nodeValue = 'http://site.com/style-member.css'
        }
    }
}
$str = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Well, yes, your first option should be quite good, however, the code I provided isn't exactly want I really want to use in a live site. I mean, almost all of them, except I don't want a `style.css` being replaced by `style-member.css`, but actually `orange.css` by `blue.css`. So, I guess this solution isn't still the one I need. I'm sorry. I should have provided the correct name. So, being this, how can I do?

Comment: Uh... it's the same.  Only where I put "style.css", you put "orange.css", and where I put "style-member.css", you put "blue.css"...

Comment: Ok, I used part of your first solution. Your solution would be the better answer in a common behavior, but since I'm using a bridge between two CMS's (the first CMS searches for a theme in the second CMS, and then mounts a child theme by merging code) I can't rely on code written on the main theme. That's why I must use a hook. The result is now this: `if (preg_match('#area\.deprogn\.com#i', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) { $event->replace('#orange\.css#i', 'blue.css'); }`. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check full domain name use

```
   if( strtolower($_SEVER['HTTP_HOST'])=='member.site.com' ){
      // other stuff
    }
```

if you need to check it with REQUEST_URI than

```
   if( preg_match('@^/member@i',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ){
      // other stuff
    }
```

to check hostname from full url

```
   if( preg_match('@^(?:http[s]*://)?([^/]+)@i',$url) ){
      // other stuff
    }
```

Note: Remember if there is really one line this will work with catching the beggining of line

```
preg_match('@^/member/@i','/member/blahstuftuff/member/member/member/me?user=amigo&dir=mber/member')
```

You can test regular expression here: [RegExp online version](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/)

---

**EDIT**

If you want to change css when the user is in member site and if is logged in a session, than just set:

`$_SESSION['member']=true;` when logins,

and do this in the part of the page (header or wherever you plan to write the css file):

USING request uri that starts with **'/member'** :
`echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://site.com/'.(preg_match('@^/member@i',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])==true&&$_SESSION['member']==true?'blue.css':'orange.css').'"/>';`

USING member domain name **'member.site.com'** :
`echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://site.com/'.(strtolower($_SEVER['HTTP_HOST'])=='member.site.com'&&$_SESSION['member']==true?'blue.css':'orange.css').'"/>';`

If you want **blue.css** to be seen by even guest users that are not logged in than just remove the session variable comparison!